# WordPress User Meta value variable into Google Gauge Chart

Tags: php, functions, javascript, html, google

I am trying to insert a Google Gauge chart on my WordPress site created with Elementor using data from WordPress user meta (current logged in user).

Using the code below, the chart is displayed with a hard-coded value of "50", however I need that value to be retrieved from the current user's user meta data field named 'sleepscore'.

My coding experience is very novice, so am not sure if I need to insert something into my theme's functions.php file, and then reference that variable instead of the "50" hard-coded value below?

```
<html>
  <head>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Exercise', 50],
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 200, height: 200,
          redFrom: 0, redTo: 33,
          yellowFrom:33, yellowTo: 66,
          greenFrom:66, greenTo: 100,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div5'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div5" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am attaching a link that may be related, but am not sure how to implement.

[Show chart in post using data passed as custom field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/374665/show-chart-in-post-using-data-passed-as-custom-field)

I believe the WordPress function get_user_meta() could be used, but again not sure how or here to use it. Perhaps something like below, but would this go in functions.php?

```
$uid = get_current_user_id();
$SLEEPscore = get_user_meta($uid,'sleepscore',true);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it wouldn't go in `functions.php`, it would go in the place where you `echo` it out, you already know how to retrieve the value because you put the solution in your final code block in your question, the missing piece of information is beginner level PHP, `echo`

Comment: I realise now though, you may not be able to use PHP, and this isn't a shortcode block or widget, but a bespoke Elementor thing. It may be that this question is impossible to answer without Elementor specific help from other Elementor users. If that is the case then you shouldn't ask here, you should seek out Elementor's support routes or find other Elementor users in an Elementor community. 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here

Comment: If you put that chart html into a php Wordpress theme template file, you could use php to get that user meta like you did, and echo the value out as a data attribute like “data-sleep_score” for your div#chart_div5. Then your JS script could get the value using something like  `let sleep_score = document.querySelector(“#chart_div5”).dataset.sleep_score;` then replace 50 with the `sleep_score` variable.